# os.listdir print more files than command `ls` but less than `ls -a`

Tags: python

I'd like to count the command in path `/Users/me/anaconda3/bin`

```
In [3]: len(os.listdir("/Users/me/anaconda3/bin"))                                                            
Out[3]: 474
```

However, when I check with commands

```
In [5]: !count=0; for f in $(ls /Users/me/anaconda3/bin) ;do count=$(( $count + 1)); done; echo $count        
470
```

However, if check all the files:

```
In [17]: ls -a /Users/me/anaconda3/bin | wc -l                                                                
476
```

What's the reason cause the difference?

Comment: Well, you could check that yourself, dont you think? For code block #1: Use `print(..)` instead of `len(..)`. For code block #2: Use: `do echo $f; count=....`. For code block #3: Remove `| wc -l `.

Comment: To surely discover the reason, do the folowing: 1) Save output of os.listdir to a file "listdir.txt" (sort list before saving) 2) Save output of "ls" to a file "ls.txt" (also, add sorting params to "ls" command, 3) Save output of "ls -a" to a file "ls-a.txt" 4) Run diff over every pair of files

Comment: Why not check in the shell with `ls /Users/me/anaconda3/bin | wc -l`? This avoids introducing unnecessary complexity..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its easy if you read the documentation of [os.listdir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir)

> Return a list containing the names of the entries in the directory
>   given by path. The list is in arbitrary order, and does not include
>   the special entries '.' and '..' even if they are present in the
>   directory.

That means the os.listdir command always has

```
no_of_elements_in(`ls -a`)-no_of_elements_in(".. and  .")
```

that is

```
len('os.listdir') =no_of_elements_in(`ls -a`)-2
```

In your case `474=476-2`